# compare an object inside a map function React

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I try to render a mapped list of activity based on props. Layout of those props are:

```
completedActivity:
  message:
  status:
  time:
  type:
  progressId:
  time:
  userId:
```

I need to compare the `completedActivity.progressId` to another set of props.

```
logData:
  timestamp:
  taskRunId:
  userName:
```

I need to see where `completedActivity.progressId = logData.taskRunId`. If they are the same I need to grab the `logData.userName`.

Here is the code to render out the activities. It is working just, but I need to add additional info to them. As of right now it will render `activity.userId`, which is a bind user and not the actual user. If they are not the same, it needs to render the bind user.

```
const ActivityList = props => {


const activityList = props.data.completedActivity.map(activity => (
    <li
        class="collection-item"
        onClick={() =>
            activity.messageDetails
                ? props.toggleMessageDetails(true, activity.messageDetails)
                : false
        }
    >
        <p>{activity.type}</p>
        <p className="message">{activity.message}</p>
        {/* 
            displays who last ran that activity and when they did. Need to come up with a better naming solution. 
        */}
        <div class="whodiditandwhen">
            <span>{activity.userId}
            </span>

            {/*<span>{activity.userId}</span>*/}
            <span>{new Date(activity.time).toLocaleString()}</span>
        </div>
        {/* 
            this will allow the user to click on the icon and see more detailed info on the activity. NOT ALL ACTIVITES HAVE THIS
        */}
        {activity.messageDetails}
    </li>
));
return (
    <ul className="activity-list">{activityList}
    </ul>
);};
```

Here is a screenshot of how it is rendered now.

[image: Pic of how it is rendered now]

Thank you

This is what I tried:

```
const userNameLog = props.data.completedActivity.map(activity => {
    let result = props.logData.find(log => log.taskRunID === activity.progressId)
    let userName = ""
        if(result === undefined){
            userName = activity.userId
        } else {
            userName = result
        }
    console.log(userName)
    }
)
```

This works to some degree except it gets rendered multiple times.

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I need to compare props.logData to props.completedActivity and see if any instance of TaskRunID is the same as progressId. If they are the same i need to get that instance of props.logData.UserName and append it to where activity.userId is now.

Comment: So you have described what you need to do. What have you tried to do to solve this? What problems have you encountered along they way?

Comment: Please [edit] your question so you can format the code for readability.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Edited

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue inside of the axios call that is getting the data before the page renders it.

```
export function getActivityUpdates(options, updateProgress) {
axios
    .post(URL, qs.stringify(options))
    .then(response => {
        // Null out saved currentActivityID if no live activity.
        handleCurrentActivityStorage(response.data.liveActivity);
        let changedIDs = [];
        let dataResponse = response.data;
        dataResponse.userId = ". . ."
        /*
        iterate over the completed activity and the log data.
        compare progress id to taskRunId.
        logData is from highest to lowest id.
        completedActivity is also from high to low but puts parents above children.
        check and make sure that it has a bind user written to it.
        Then if taskrunid is = to or less than the progressId. change it and add it to the changedIDs array.
        the ChangedIds array makes sure that ids are not iterated over multiple times.
        set the userID to the actual username found in the logs.
        */

        dataResponse.completedActivity.forEach(data => {

            options.logData.forEach(log => {

                //
                if (
                    data.userId === options.bindUsername &&
                    !changedIDs.includes(data.progressId) &&
                    (log.taskRunID === data.progressId ||
                    log.taskRunID < data.progressId)) {
                    changedIDs.push(data.progressId)
                    data.userId = log.magUserName;
                }
            })
        });
        updateProgress(dataResponse);

        // Exit function if a task is not running
        if (!response.data.liveActivity.length) {
            return;
        }


        // Get updated data every second until task is complete
        setTimeout(
            getActivityUpdates.bind(null, options, updateProgress),
            1000
        );
    })
    .catch(() => showErrorMessage(options.command));
```

}